# Django ORM query with multiple joins

Tags: python, mysql, django, join, orm

I've been trying to come up with the django version of this query and I can't seem to get it.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM answer a
LEFT JOIN groups g
  ON a.group_id = g.id
LEFT JOIN group_permissions gp
  ON g.id = gp.group_id
WHERE gp.user_id = '77777';
```

I've been trying something like this:

```
answers = Answer.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).prefetch_related('group__grouppermissions')
```

Answers are associated to groups. Groups are associated to multiple users. Group permissions are associated to groups and users.

I'm sure I'm missing some relationship somewhere.

Models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Answer(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Groups', models.DO_NOTHING)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'answer'

class Groups(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'groups'

class GroupPermissions(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey('Groups', models.DO_NOTHING)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING)
    role = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'group_permissions'
```

Comment: Answer is not associated with groups at all. how are your models defined ?

Comment: Answer is associated to groups. Answer has a group id (foreign key) that maps to group:id (pk).

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit association django creates for you: `group_grouppermissions_set`. You can read about it in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) about many-to-one relationship.

So your query will look like something like this:

```
answers = Answer.objects.\
    filter(group__grouppermissions_set__user_id=77777)
```

Also notice that django will create `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Then when you will confident that your query is working you can add optimization like `prefetch_related` to it with similar lookups. It depends on how deep you want to fetch from `Answer` model.